# How to check that each list in a list of list is the same length

Tags: python, list

I have a list and a list of list

```
A=["grp 1", "grp 2"]
B=[["1","2"],["3","4"],["5","6"]]
```

how do I check that each list in B is equal to the length of A?

I would like something like

```
if len(A) != len(list in B):
     raise ValueError('special error message')
```

Comment: `all(len(x) == len(A) for x in B)`

Comment: how do I do not all equal instead?

Comment: I want to raise an error if not all equal vs. checking that they are all equal

Answer (score 3):

If you want to make sure that **every single element of `B` is not equal to the length of `A`** then you can use:

```
a_len = len(A)
all(len(x) != a_len for x in B)
```

Alternatively you can use the following if you want to see if **any** element of `B` is not the same length as `A`:

```
a_len = len(A)
any(len(x) != a_len for x in B)
```

So in your case you could use:

```
a_len = len(A)
if any(len(x) != a_len for x in B):
    raise error
```

Comment: You should probably extract `len(A)` instead of doing it in the loop on every iteration

Answer (score 0):

as additional note, if you want to know if every element in the list have the same  length regardless of its value, you can use

```
len( set( len(x) for x in my_list ) ) == 1
```

with set you eliminate all duplicates so if in the end if its length is more than one then some stuff there have different size